# Jboss EAP 6.4 Module resource-root path

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-modules

I tried to create Jboss module that includes jks and jar files.
Though I am able to make it work, but I don't understand why it works.
When I define resource-root for both jar and jks files.

`<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="my.module">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="foo.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="mykey.jks"/>
    </resources>
</module>`

I get the following error:

> org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root 'mykey.jks' at path 'mykey.jks' (position: END_TAG seen ..."foo.jar"/> \r\n    ... @3:42) caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

But if I define the resource-root as `<resource-root path="."/>` everything works fine.

Does anyone knows why it works when I use "." as resource-root path?
What's the magic that Jboss did?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors):

> A resource root is a specification of a location where the class
>   loader for a module will look for classes and resources. Each module
>   has zero or more resource roots, though most regular modules will
>   contain exactly one, which refers to the JAR file with the module's
>   content.

In human terms, resource-root is meant to be used for a directory or a .zip file (which .jar, .rar etc files also are). A jks file is not a .zip file or a directory, so you get an error opening a .zip file.

Once a keystore (.jks) file is in the classpath, it can be loaded through KeyStore abstraction. A keystore file needs to be in classpath as-such, so that is why specifying the dot as resource root works. JBoss didn't actually do any magic there.

Answer (score 2):

Try to give resource root's path and name attributes.
If you give path attribute only, jboss will try to open it with  zip util

eg:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="az.ac.localit">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="." name="travel_app.properties"></resource-root>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Comment: OP stated that loading works just fine with path attribute only when using the dot, which directly contradicts with your answer